# Using MAX shuffles records around

Tags: mysql, max

I have the following influences table:

[image]

I need to get the latest influence for a stakeholder...

I have the following query but it's mixing up the row data because MAX isn't returning a full record:

```
SELECT stakeholder_id, MAX(created_at) AS maxca, influence
FROM influences
WHERE
project_id = 1 AND
deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY stakeholder_id
```

[image]

You can see that the influence against that maxca and stakeholder_id should be 3, not 5.

How do I overcome this issue?
My full existing statement was this:

```
SELECT `stakeholders`.*, `influences`.`influence`
FROM `project_stakeholder`
INNER JOIN `stakeholders` ON `project_stakeholder`.`stakeholder_id` = `stakeholders`.`id`
INNER JOIN `stakeholder_profiles` ON `stakeholder_profiles`.`stakeholder_id` = `stakeholders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `stakeholder_profile_tag` ON `stakeholder_profile_tag`.`stakeholder_profile_id` = `stakeholder_profiles`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `stakeholder_profile_group` ON `stakeholder_profile_group`.`stakeholder_profile_id` = `stakeholder_profiles`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `influences` ON `influences`.`stakeholder_id` = `stakeholders`.`id`
INNER JOIN `projects` ON `project_stakeholder`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`


LEFT JOIN (

    /*! This is the bit that doesn't work */
    SELECT stakeholder_id, MAX(created_at) AS maxca
    FROM influences
    WHERE
    project_id = 1 AND
    deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY stakeholder_id


) 

iu ON `iu`.`stakeholder_id` = influences.stakeholder_id AND 
iu.maxca = influences.created_at



WHERE `projects`.`id` = '1'
GROUP BY `stakeholders`.`id`
```

**This seems to work:**

```
SELECT `stakeholders`.*, iu.influence
FROM `project_stakeholder`
INNER JOIN `stakeholders` ON `project_stakeholder`.`stakeholder_id` = `stakeholders`.`id`
INNER JOIN `stakeholder_profiles` ON `stakeholder_profiles`.`stakeholder_id` = `stakeholders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `stakeholder_profile_tag` ON `stakeholder_profile_tag`.`stakeholder_profile_id` = `stakeholder_profiles`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `stakeholder_profile_group` ON `stakeholder_profile_group`.`stakeholder_profile_id` = `stakeholder_profiles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `projects` ON `project_stakeholder`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`


LEFT JOIN (

    select i1.*
    from influences i1
    join
    (
        SELECT stakeholder_id, MAX(created_at) AS maxca
        FROM influences
        WHERE project_id = 1 
        AND deleted_at IS NULL
        GROUP BY stakeholder_id
    ) i2 on i1.stakeholder_id = i2.stakeholder_id
        and i1.created_at = i2.maxca

) iu ON `iu`.`stakeholder_id` = stakeholders.id



WHERE `projects`.`id` = '1'
GROUP BY `stakeholders`.`id`
```

Comment: Your `group by` is invalid SQL. MySQL chooses to return random results instead (they call it indeterminate). Every other DBMS would simply reject that statement. See here for details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select i1.*
from influences i1
join
(
    SELECT stakeholder_id, MAX(created_at) AS maxca
    FROM influences
    WHERE project_id = 1 
    AND deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY stakeholder_id
) i2 on i1.stakeholder_id = i2.stakeholder_id
    and i1.created_at = i2.maxca
```

Comment: This works, but I can't seem to get it into my existing statement, could you give me a hand?

Comment: At the top: Don't select `iu.influence`. Select `influences.influence`. And you can remove the redundant columns from the inner select.

Comment: I have re-posted my code, with the change you made, but it still returns 5 instead of 3. thanks for your patience man.

Comment: I think the issue is now the second influences join required.

Comment: Use an `inner join` and no `left join`

Comment: That oddly works, but if  there is no influence to join with, it obviously fails. I have added my OP with a solution I got to work, not sure if it's the most stupid join ever though :)